# gnuplot autotitle matrix from header comment

Tags: gnuplot

If I have matrix data with a header comment, can I use that as the title? The data looks something like:

```
# Information on my plot, the time (t=2.0), for example
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 9 8
7 6 5 4
```

I have tried `set key autotitle columheader` to try to use the entire commented line as a title, but no title is printed.

Also, how would this be accomplished for multiple data sets within the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
From the documentation (under "help index")

```
`index '<name>'` selects the data set with name '<name>'.  Names are assigned
 to data sets in comment lines.  The comment character and leading white space
 are removed from the comment line.  If the resulting line starts with <name>,
 the following data set is now named <name> and can be selected.

 Example:
       plot 'file' index 'Population'

 Please note that every comment that starts with <name> will name the following
 data set.  To avoid problems it may be useful to choose a naming scheme like
 '== Population ==' or '[Population]'.
```

Here is a demo

```
$DATA << EOD
# Ones
0 1
1 0


#Twos
0 2
2 0


#Threes
0 3
3 0
EOD

set view 77, 330
set ztics 1
set hidden3d nooffset
set key box

splot for [name in "Ones Threes Twos"] \
      $DATA index name matrix with lines lw 3 title name
```

[image]

Comment: What if all of your headers are very similar, for example, something like `#Data at t=0` and `#Data at t=1`?

Comment: You can select using any leading substring of what is really in the file. For example: `plot $DATA index 'Data at t=1' matrix with pm3d`   But be careful with that leading substring implication.  That command would also match 'Data at t=10', which is why the docs suggest using a trailing character sequence.

Comment: I suppose you have answered the question as I posed it, but it's not exactly what I want. What I would like to do is use a numerical value for `index`, since there are many datasets, and loop over the index, grabbing the header for each one as a title. Maybe that's not possible without using something more specialized like sed or awk?